# problem with primefaces schedule

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, primefaces

i have tried to write a simple page containing scheduler

it looks fine but the listeners like

eventSelectListener,dateSelectListener,eventMoveListener never fired!

what is the problem

this is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" prefix="p"%>

<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
   <base href="<%=basePath%>">

   <title>My JSF 'Calendar.jsp' starting page</title>

   <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
   <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
   <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">   
   <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
   <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
   <!--
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
   -->

</head>

<body>
   <f:view>
   <p:resources/>
      <h:form>
      <p:schedule value="#{ScheduleBean.model}" editable="true"  aspectRatio="4"
      eventSelectListener="#{ScheduleBean.onEventSelect}"
      dateSelectListener="#{ScheduleBean.onDateSelect}"
      eventMoveListener="#{ScheduleBean.onEventMove}"
      >
      </p:schedule>
      </h:form>
   </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

and my back bean is:

```
package com.pardis.calendar.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.primefaces.event.DateSelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntryMoveEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntrySelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultScheduleModel;
import org.primefaces.model.ScheduleModel;

import com.fanava.genericmanagedbeans.utls.ManagedBeanUtils;
import com.pardis.calendar.dm.calendar.CalendarBean;
import com.pardis.calendar.dm.user.UserBean;

public class ScheduleBean {
   private ScheduleModel model;
   private int userId;
   private int systemId;

   public int getSystemId() {
      return 1;
   }

   public void setSystemId(int systemId) {
      this.systemId = systemId;
   }

   public ScheduleBean() {
      model = new DefaultScheduleModel();
   }
   @PostConstruct
   public void Initialize() {
      ...
   }
   public void onEventSelect(ScheduleEntrySelectEvent selectEvent){
      System.out.println("done");
   }
   public void onDateSelect(DateSelectEvent selectEvent) {
      System.out.println("done");
      }
   public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent selectEvent) {
      System.out.println("move");
      }

   public ScheduleModel getModel() {
      return model;
   }

   public int getUserId() {
      return 1;
   }

   public void setUserId(int userId) {
      this.userId = userId;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my events not showing up. As it turns out I had nested form and outputLabel elements that would not allow the schedule to render properly. I am not sure why but once I minimized the nesting it rendered just fine. Just throwing that out there.

Answer (score 0):

The `<p:resources/>` sould be placed inside the `<head>`. Check chapter 2.3 of the [User Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_260710.pdf).

Unrelated to the problem, I strongly recommend to abandon JSP and go use its successor Facelets.

Comment: thanks, changing the <p:/resources> position does not help!
i have tried to use faceclet but i was unsuccessfull!
could you please answer my post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598738/how-to-make-facelet-work
thanks

Comment: thanks now facelet works. but it does not show events! also the above problem has not been solved!

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.2 or 2.0? I have the impression that you were using JSF 1.2 and are reading guidelines/tutorials targeted on JSF 2.0 which leads to all the problems and confusion. If your servletcontainer is capable of it, I recommend to go for JSF 2.0.

Comment: i am using myfaces api 1.2.7. i can't go for JSF2.0, how can i use this component on my configuration? is any specific tutorial available?

Comment: Oh, it's MyFaces 1.2? Okay.. Why can't you go for JSF 2.0? Well, after all you need to carefully read the JSF 1.2 specific instructions in PrimeFaces guide and another places. Sorry, I can't be of more assistance since I can't tell from top of head how PrimeFaces 2 + JSF 1.2 is supposed to work together. In future questions, I strongly recommend to mention the JSF impl/version used to avoid confusions and red herrings in question/answers.

Comment: i am using primefaces-1.0.2.jar which compatible with JSF1.2!